I didn't use "com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3" in project gradle in android studio
I didn't use "com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3" in my project gradle but why the below warning is occured

:app » com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0 [Prevents app release in
Google Play Console] com.google.android.play:core version 1.10.0 has
been reported as problematic by its author and will block publishing
of your app to Play Console. Note: Update your Play Core Maven
dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core
library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which
introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to
improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play
requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the
latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration

My project gradle (app level) is available below:
`
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        //compileSdkVersion 34
        compileSdk 34
        applicationId 'com.example.app'
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true



    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    namespace 'com.example.app'

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'


    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0'

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.5.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'


    // CameraX dependencies
    def camerax_version = "1.4.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$camerax_version"

// ML Kit dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:text-recognition:16.0.1'
    // ML-Kit to identify the language of the recognized text
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:language-id:17.0.6'

    // ML-Kit to translate the recognized text
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:translate:17.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:playstore-dynamic-feature-support:16.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.12.0'

}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'`

When I upload the app bundle the below error is occurred:
enter image description here

try any of the ways listed here to check what dependency you're using is using play:core: How do I show dependencies tree in Android Studio?

Did you find the issue?
I found that com.google.mlkit:playstore-dynamic-feature-support:16.0.0-beta2 would pull in a version of com.google.android.play:core
Need to find a replacement for it.

Yes I resolved by JustSightseeing's answer
